# How Do I Track An Event With No CSS Selector

Tags: javascript, css, react-360

I'm currently using Adobe DTM to track events on our sites.

Right now I'm dealing with a site that's coded mostly with ReactVR and then slapped onto a regular HTML page through ECMA6.

Now I'm trying to track an event using the following code but placing this into the app. But DTM is requiring a CSS selector which I can't even create because none of these events are driven by ReactVR and not a traditional DOM.

```js
var inventoryCollect = new CustomEvent(‘inventoryCollect’, ‘detail’: {‘item_id’: ’Margarita'});
dispatchEvent(inventoryCollect);
```

Is there a way around this?

Please let me know if my question isn't clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: Basically, the Adobe DTM system requires a CSS selector to fire an event tracking action. However, the current page I'm dealing with doesn't really have any objects that are wrapped in a CSS selector or even closely associated one. Make sense? I'm still learning how to ask questions.

Comment: If there are objects in the DOM? Are these objects divs? Buttons? You mentioned it was in a HTML doc. If so, try the `<tagName>` and/or pseudo-classes that indicate a state like `:focus`, or `disabled="false"` attribute?

Comment: There is no traditional DOM, the site lives inside an HTML5 canvas rendering WebGL contents.

Comment: _"the site lives inside an HTML5 canvas"_ Have you tried using `document.querySelector("canvas")` ?

Comment: I can try it in the next iteration. thanks for the suggestion.